# KONG workspace creation from automated way

Tags: api, api-gateway, kong

I am new to the KONG, just checking if we can create the workspace in KONG from any API or from any automated way. I tried to check in KONG docs and other forum also but did not find any answer.

Any leads would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems quite straightforward from the documentation:

https://docs.konghq.com/enterprise/2.6.x/admin-api/workspaces/reference/

Just do a POST on the admin API `/workspaces/`

Workspace is a feature from the entreprise version not the OSS, not sure you will get lot of help from the community on this part

Comment: To emphasis on Orel's comment on this feature. Yes, updating/creating workspace is NOT supported in OSS version. You'll get below error: ```{
    "message": "Enterprise license missing or expired"
}```